# back button title color not changed while we open popover or present form controller in iOS 13

Tags: swift, iphone, sdk, ios13

In iOS 13 back button title color not dimmed whenever we open popover or present other controller. Other part of application grayed out but not back button.

also `tintColorDidChange` function is not available for `UIBarButtonItem` so is there any way to do grayed out all back button titles.

Note: Back button image is being grayed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try by changing tint color of bar button?
I got same problem and solved by using

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red // put your desire color
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: My issue is when you are in detail screen which has back button and color is red after then you present new controller or popover then back button of previous screen should be grayed out like default behaviour in iOS 12

Comment: When you press back button then you must change the previous button color to your desire color